# Identify all occurrences of a list of images in a screenshot (find image in image)

Tags: image, opencv, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to identify all occurrences of a list of images in a screenshot and get the label of the emoji (e.g. "smile").

The list of images holds all emojis ([full list](https://api.github.com/emojis)): [image]
[image]
[image] and so on…

And this is the screenshot ([show large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdQsd.png)):

[image]

The screenshots can have different resolutions and different heights where the emoji occur.

My ideas were:

- Using OpenCV and a variety of filtering and iterate all emoji images over it (maybe using [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html))
- Using neural networks like tensorflow, training your own model with the emojis

How would you do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several classic ways to answer your problem:

- Simple regular correlation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation.
  The simple correlation is used when you have exactly the image you are looking for, with no change in intensity.
- Normalized correlation (math behind template matching): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching.
  The simple correlation is used when you have exactly the image you are looking for, with no change in intensity.

If you have different intensities between your screenshot and your emoji base picture, you should use normalized correlation.

Both these methods will give you an image with peaks, and your emojis will be localized at the local maxima of this image.
As your emojis can be very similar to one another, you will have to use a threshold on the correlation image in order to discriminate between the emoji you are testing and the ones that look nearly like him.

This method can be time consuming, but can be easily speed-up by using an image pyramid.
An image pyramid is a set of image where the first one is your image, the second one is a subsampling of the first by a factor of 2, and so on:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing).
Then the correlation is applyed on the top level of the pyramid to find an approximate location, then on the top - 1 level around the approxiamte location and so on.

About the neural network, or other machine learning methods you want to try, they are really heavy solutions and you have a pretty simple problem, so you should normaly don't need them.
You have the exact picture you are looking for, without rotation, deformation  or intensity change, and the template matching should be very effective.